# Feature class parameters changing in saved models

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, parameters

I am building models in ModelBuilder, I add an "Append" geoprocess to a blank model, bring in the input and target Feature Classes (FC) from the Table of Contents (ToC) to link into the Append, assign the field mapping, save model and run it, everything works.

I quit ArcGIS Pro and eventually relaunch with the same project file but I remove the initial input table FC from the ToC and load a new GDB into my ToC with the same FC names, in the same hierarchy in the ToC. Destination FC has not changed, only input table, and input table is named and pathed same in ToC.  I launch the model but now the input and destination FC's are showing me unrelated FC's in the ToC.

Why do my input and target FC's in the model defaults change to something they were not when I saved the model?

Comment: You can edit your question, to correct errors, add images etc. So now you identified a mistake in your question, correct it! You can also remove comments when they become obsolete. Also final note avoid using abbreviations, not everyone speaks English as a first language and wont necessarily know what FC or TOC means...

Comment: Question has been edited for clarity

Comment: Having replaced the layers in the contents pane and with modelbuilder open, try validating it first before you run it? Also in the Append tool, you may need to click on the reset field mapping button. I find tools that use field mapping highly problematic with subsequent runs of the model.